# Getting Version error in mongoDB while using save() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am getting this version error in MongoDB due to the `save()` method. I did some research about it and got to know that the save method uses versioning. To skip it we can use the update method, but by using update, I am getting another error "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id".

Is there any other way to solve this version error?

code example:

```
let fileDoc = await File.findById(req.params.id);

    fileDoc.history.unshift({
      user: req.user._id,
      status: status,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });

    if (is_false_reject) {
      fileDoc.isFalseReject = is_false_reject;
      fileDoc.falseRejectedAt = new Date();
    }

    fileDoc.status = status;
    fileDoc.comment = comment;
    await fileDoc.save();
```

Error by save() method:
VersionError: No matching document found for id "e6a83b9b-42be-41b7-87ed-e21eff052c61.pdf" version 2 modifiedPaths "history, status"
at generateVersionError (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:439:10)
at model.Model.save (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:495:28)
at /home/node/app/helpers/file.js:525:23
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5) {
version: 2,
modifiedPaths: [
'history',
'status'
]

Answer (score 0):

Please look on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey

We can disable the version key in mongoose but that is not a best practice, Please review the documentation.

> If you face issue after this solution please comment, I will try my best to solve your issue

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.